# Black Flicker just after splash screen is shown - WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, flicker

There is a black flicker for a fraction of a second just after the splash screen is shown.  The main page is image heavy, probably it is because of that. While debugging I can see that some symbols are being loaded? Is it due to that? Is there any way to mask it? Or how do I show the MainPage faster with out the flicker. Can I preload the MainPage while the splash screen is shown?

Comment: Microsoft recommended noto to use images larger than 2000x2000, however you should consider decreasing its quality.

Comment: these are really small images. And the flicker is only when the app starts.

Comment: Try setting image control CacheMode="BitmapCache"